# Cant get button onclicklistener to work with listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list view that is clickable along with a button in it that is also clickable. Problem is I cant get the button to do anything ( it shows the click/highlight but my action isnt performed ).

here is my Photo.class:

```
public class Photos extends MyBaseMenuOptions implements OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos);
            LayoutInflater inflater = Photos.this.getLayoutInflater();

            final View buttonView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            Button button = (Button) buttonView.findViewById(R.id.trash);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    ...

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

I also have a `@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {` in the class but that works when you click the listview

Here is my list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp"         />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/trash"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" 

         />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You say in one comment that you do not have any Adapter, but in your code you use listView.setAdapter() method. So i downvote your question : illogical

Comment: @YvesDelerm i am new to java and since i didnt implement it at the top with my class I didnt think I was using one.

Comment: OK, no problem. If you want, you can make an edit (even a small one) one your question so that I am able to upvote it. May I just advice you to take the time to know how adapters work, for instance here : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set the onClickListener on the button within the adapter.

Something like that :

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

//fill your cell

```
        Button button = (Button) buttonView.findViewById(R.id.trash);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

}

Comment: I dont have a getView to override

Comment: Dont you have a getView() method in your CustomListViewAdapter ? Every class implementing Adapter or ListAdapter have one of this.

Answer (score 1):

so i had same problem 
xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/beam_contact_entry_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/sv_standard_padding"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:background="?entry_background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_top_letter"
        style="?primary_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?entry_background"
        android:visibility="gone"        
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_top_line_fit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sv_stripe_height_for_header"
        android:layout_below="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_top_letter"
        android:visibility="gone"
        layout="@layout/svyaznoy_stripe" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_top_line_slim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_top_line_fit"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="?divider_background" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/beam_contact_entry_contact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/sv_standard_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/sv_standard_padding"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_top_line_slim"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/beam_contact_entry_invite"
        android:background="?entry_background" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_info_avatar" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_entry_text"
                style="?primary_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alexander Great"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_entry_text_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                android:text="mobile"
                android:visibility="gone"
                style="?secondary_text"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <ru.fon.svyaznoy.ui.UserpicImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_info_avatar"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_picture_side"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_picture_side"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sv_no_userpic" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/beam_contact_entry_invite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/beam_contact_entry_contact"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/beam_contact_entry_contact"
        android:background="?entry_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >   

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/beam_contact_fragment_entry_right_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?entry_background"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sv_svyaznoy_contact" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in adapter in method getView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    View childview1 = view.findViewById(R.id.beam_contact_entry_contact)
    childview1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // your text
            }
    });
    View childview2 = view.findViewById(R.id.beam_contact_entry_invite);
    childview2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // your text 2
            }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to write click event for button in the adapter.
write the click event for button in the get view method of adapter and there only you will get the button instance.
good luck

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              LayoutInflator inflater = LayoutInflator.from(context);
              if(convertview == null {
                convertview = inflater .inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
               }                
               Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trash);
                  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
       return convertview;
```

May this works fine 
good luck

Comment: Can you give me an example, not really sure what you mean